# How to access OIDC client information in Keycloak E-Mail templates?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, freemarker

I know how to access some variable information in Keycloak E-Mail templates. E.g.:

```
user.getUsername()
user.getEmail()
user.getFirstName()
user.getLastName()
```

But I need to access client specific variables. The Keycloak Java Code shows there is all information I need in the `ClientModel` Java Class: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/server-spi/src/main/java/org/keycloak/models/ClientModel.java

```
client.getClientId()
client.getName()
client.getDescription()
client.getRootUrl()
client.getBaseUrl()
client.getAttribute(name)
```

And the `client_id=account` Query Parameter is also set on the page, where the password reset action is triggered:

`https://example.com/auth/realms/my-realm/login-actions/reset-credentials?client_id=account&tab_id=bQiVx012SZg`

[image: password reset page]

The information is set on the client:

[image: keycloak web ui client settings]

But the client varaible seems to be unset while the email template gets rendered.

[image: rendering error]

```
# password-reset.ftl

# This does NOT work
${client.name}

# This does NOT work
${kcSanitize(msg("clientinfohtml",client.getName()))?no_esc}
```

**How to access client variables in Keycloak E-Mail templates?**

Answer (score 1):

Yep, *client* segment seems not accessible and give `https://null` !

But if you check availabilty of segment it is not empty!

```
<#if client?? && client['baseUrl']?? && client['baseUrl']?has_content>
  <img height="100" src='${client["rootUrl"]}/${kcSanitize(msg("emailSignatureLogoUrl"))?no_esc}' style="max-width: 250px;">
<#else>
  <img height="100" src='${kcSanitize(msg("emailSignatureLogoUrl"))?no_esc}' style="max-width: 250px;">
</#if>
```

This is the same result with client['rootUrl']

Searching an anwser, I have found this topics about Model provisioning for EmailTemplate:
https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/access-to-group-attributes-in-custom-email-template/10874/2